# How to set up a test environment for linked data

Tags: testing, dns, rdf, linked-data

I'm wondering how to set up a stage/test environment for a linked-data infrastructure.

Indeed, in my organization we have the prerequisite to always have test env together with a prod env. Until here nothing abnormal. However, this can be complicate for linked-data where the data are identified by URI. The URI is central to linked-data.

How can you set up a test environment with the same uri(s) as the production environment ?

The only thing that i see are:

A sort of private network where to set some DNS rules that says that when in that environment, the uri should redirect to that test machine IP.

While outside of the that VPN, the machine should be the one that an internet DNS point to.

The other solution is having a reverse proxy like ngnix which does url rewrite. Hence you would adress the test machine with a local url and this url, will be re-injected in the response by the reverse proxy with a rewrite. But that's just too heavy and could only work with rdfa. I don't know if a reverse proxy can pasrse a full turtle file.

final solution, changing the base uri of your data each time.

Please any suggestion ?

Comment: I think this is too broad for Stack Overflow, but there may be a specific technical problem that you can tease out here.  (Or maybe a version of this would be more suitable on Programmers.SE.)  However, just because data is *identified* by IRIs in linked-data settings doesn't mean anything about *where* data *comes from*.  If you have some black box that takes an IRI and returns some data about it (presumably by launching an external request), you can easily set up a mock black box that does the same thing for a testing environment but doesn't make an external request. It's really no...

Comment: ...different from what you'd have to do to test a database connection;  you wouldn't actually run tests against your production database, but you'd have something in the test environment that *acts* like the production database.